# Delete feature from multiple layers with Leaflet.draw

Tags: leaflet

There are multiple layers displayed in a map and I'd like to have a delete button to delete selected markers from these layers.

I am using Leaflet.draw plugin to implement that, but it seems that the draw control has to be bind to a single layer whereas I have multiple layers.

I tried to copy all features in layers to a FeatureGroup and bind the FeatureGroup with drawing control to accomplish that, but it broke the Layers control behavior since I cannot control the visibility of layers anymore.  (Duplicated features in FeatureGroup).

Is there any way to enable multiple layer feature deleting without breaking layer visibility control?

http://jsfiddle.net/mdqvpLvx/7/

```
var layerControl = new L.Control.Layers({}, {});

var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(data);
geojsonLayer.getLayers()[0].addTo(drawnItems);

var geojsonLayer2 = L.geoJson(data2);
geojsonLayer2.getLayers()[0].addTo(drawnItems);

map.addControl(layerControl);
layerControl.addOverlay(geojsonLayer, 'layer1');
layerControl.addOverlay(geojsonLayer2, 'layer2');
```

Comment: Do you have testcase (preferrably a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/)) and some relevant code?

Comment: That Fiddle throws errors like crazy and does not even work. When you have a working fiddle, please add it to your question by editing it, thats much clearer for other users.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that caused by the https link.  I've modified that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I still have to keep copies of the markers in FeatureCollection layer and delete them accordingly from particular layers in drawDelete event.  And add/remove markers from FeatureCollection layer when layers visibility changes from LayerControl.

```
    // Draw Control
    var editableFeatures = L.featureGroup();
    map.addLayer(editableFeatures);
    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
        draw: false,
        edit: {
            edit: false,
            featureGroup: editableFeatures
        }
    });

    map.on('draw:deleted', function(e) {
        var layers = e.layers;
        layers.eachLayer(function(feature) {
            map.eachLayer(function(mapLayer) {
                if (mapLayer.hasLayer) {
                    mapLayer.removeLayer(feature);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    map.addControl(drawControl);

    //LayerControl
    var layerControl = new L.Control.Layers({}, {});
    map.addControl(layerControl);

    map.on('overlayadd', function(layer, name) {
        layer.layer.eachLayer(function(feature) {
            editableFeatures.addLayer(feature);
        });
    });

    map.on('overlayremove', function(layer, name) {
        layer.layer.eachLayer(function(feature) {
            editableFeatures.removeLayer(layer);
        });
    });
```

Comment: ```if (mapLayer.hasLayer)``` is going to be truthy more often than you expect (or you really are checking the method exists, in which case it looks enough like a bug to merit a comment IMO).